# Hide "New item or edit this list" link with custom action

Tags: list-view, custom-action, hide-elements

is there some way I can hide the "New item or edit this list" link above a list's ListViewWebPart? I have tried searching for the link's Action ID online but found nothing.

EDIT: For clarification, I can't set the toolbar type to "None". Please see my other question [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/247226/hide-new-item-button-in-ribbon-of-a-specific-sharepoint-2013-list/247415#247415) for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If you edit the Web part, you can edit the toolbar type to No Toolbar. Your *New Item* and *Edit this list* effectively disappears :)

[image]

## Edit

If that removes your custom action, you need to hide the two buttons by using JQuery (or any other framework of your choice). The following code hides the entire toolbar, but you need to find the `ID` or `class` of each button to make the code workk for you.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
var test=  $('tr').find('td.ms-list-addnew.ms-textXLarge.ms-list-addnew-aligntop.ms-soften');
console.log(test);
test.hide();
});
</script>
```

Reference: [How I can hide the new item/edit toolbar in SharePoint 2013 via JQuery](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/00117f5c-1dd6-46e9-a33d-e16b51eab5d9/how-i-can-hide-the-new-itemedit-toolbar-in-sharepoint-2013-via-jquery?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Comment: I can't set the toolbar type to none as I also hide the ribbon's "New" group using a custom action and SP seems to have a bug where setting the toolbar type to "None" will negate that custom action. I don't know why SP does this. That's why  I wanted to hide the "New item or edit this list" with with a custom action approach.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @LeonidasFett I edited my answer accordingly.